# How does a Haskell list comprehension output a result which is one integer?

Tags: haskell, casting, list-comprehension

I am trying to use a list comprehension to find the median of a list which will always contain three integers with the following function:

```
midNum set = [x | x <- set, x /= maximum set, x /= minimum set]!!0
```

This works well enough on its own, as in the following example:

```
ghci> midNum [1,2,3]
2
```

However, it blows up when I try to use it in conjunction with my other functions, resulting in the following error:

```
*** Exception: Prelude.!!: index too large
```

When I remove the '!!0', the compiler gives me this message:

```
Triangle.hs:4:79: error:
* Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ [t]
* In the second argument of `(+)', namely
    `squareOf (midNum triangle)'
  In the second argument of `(==)', namely
    `squareOf (minimum triangle) + squareOf (midNum triangle)'
  In the expression:
    squareOf (maximum triangle)
    == squareOf (minimum triangle) + squareOf (midNum triangle)
* Relevant bindings include
    triangle :: [t] (bound at Triangle.hs:4:9)
    isRight :: [t] -> Bool (bound at Triangle.hs:4:1)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

So it looks as if the function is giving me an integer, but the compiler is expecting a list. In another language I would typecast to fix this, but I'm not sure what to do in Haskell.

This is also essentially my first dip into Haskell, so forgive me if the answer is blindingly obvious.

Comment: Could you add the code that results in an error? Your example should evaluate to a list containing one element. Your example won't typecheck unless you use `minimum` and `maximum` instead of `min` and `max`

Comment: If you know the list is always 3 elements long and just want the median, why not use `sort list !! 1`?

Comment: I am away from my main computer atm, so I can't upload the errors.

Comment: Also, I was unaware of the sort function. However, this issue with types seems to be something which will come up again, so I would like to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Which `min` are you using? `min :: Ord a => a -> a -> a`, so passing it a list shouldn't type-check.

Comment: I postulate your `medVal` function won't work well for inputs like `[1,1,2]` or `[3,3,3]`, even if they are only three elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't think this will work since in order to calculate the *minimum* and *maximum* **of a list**, you need to use `minimum` and `maximum` ; not `min` and `max`. So a quick fix is:

```
medVal list = [out | out <- list, out /= minimum list, out /= maximum list]
```

> and when I try to send out the 0th element within the function by adding "!! 0" to the end of the function, it tells me that that's an invalid operation for an integer.

You can write it as:

```
medVal :: Ord a => [a] -> a
medVal list = [out | out <- list, out /= minimum list, out /= maximum list]!!0
```

or more elegantly (and faster):

```
medVal :: Ord a => [a] -> a
medVal list = head [out | out <- list, out /= minimum list, out /= maximum list]
```

Nevertheless if you know for sure you will **receive three elements**, I don't know if it is good design to use a list anyway: you could define a function taking three arguments, or a function taking a tuple of elements.

Finally your function **will error if two or more elements are equivalent** (like `medVal [0,0,20]`) for instance, since it will filter out all elements and thus `head` will not find a single element.

Comment: Thanks! I was writing from memory, so not everything carried over. I did use the minimum and maximum functions. I will try this fix when I get back.

Comment: @MasterArcanist: note that - as is specified in the last paragraph - your function is still not semantically sound.

Comment: I was responding to your post before the edit. I am unfamiliar with the double colon, Ord a, =>, etc. This problem arose when trying to figure out a solution to  a problem concerning right triangles on page 21 of "Learn you a Haskell for great good", using only what I had learned up to that point.

Comment: @MasterArcanist: the double colon is to specify a **type signature**. You do not have to specify it, it is however nice to know what the type is of the function's operands and the type of the result.

Comment: @MasterArcanist Don't post from memory; wait until you are at a computer where you can *confirm* that the posted code actually behaves the way you claim it does.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I've fixed the post. It looks like the entire issue is just me getting confused. It is indeed the problem with inputting lists with one or more equivalent values tripping me up, as well as being confused when running the function in ghci and getting what appeared to be only an integer.

Answer (score 2):

a more elementary solution

```
> let midVal x y z | (z>=x)==(x>=y) = x
                   | (x>=y)==(y>=z) = y
                   | otherwise      = z
```

Note: typo fixed

It's derived from the truth table, but easy to read the lines, for example if either x is less than z and greater than y or x is greater than z and y is greater than x (so x is in the middle) etc.

Comment: `midVal 2 5 4` returns `2` ? Anyway, the logic above is non-trivial -- some explanation would help.

Comment: For some reason this works when interpreted but not when I run it through the compiler. Any idea why? In both cases the text was copy/pasted with only newline/spacing changed.

Comment: `let` is required in the ghci environment, in compiled code you should remove it.

Comment: I did remove let.